# taxonomy CSV import in linux

Tags: taxonomy-terms

taxonomy CSV import
  How do use taxonomy CSV import the Chinese characters in linux ,Now I import all is empty
Thank you for your help me to answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this module to import taxnonomy terms with any translations [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv)

Comment: Yes, I now is to use the module, just import Chinese newspaper is empty, when under the Windows USES the module is imported Chinese has no problem